# multi-dimensional state in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How can I make multidimensional state in compose that also effects the source the state came from?
I tried to ask this question without code previously and it wasn't clear. This is a little more code than necessary, but I will be able to communicate my problem

```
data class Record(
    var duration: Int,
    val timeStamp: Instant = Clock.System.now(),
    var description: String? = null
)

data class Task(
    var name: String,
    var defaultAmount: Int,
    val completions: MutableList<Record> = mutableListOf()
) {
  fun createRecord(description: String? = null, duration: Int = defaultAmount): Record {
    val record = Record(duration, description = description)
    completions.add(record)
    return record
  }
}

class SourceOfTruth(private val thisSavesMeTyping: MutableList<Task> = mutableListOf()) :
    MutableCollection<Task> by thisSavesMeTyping {
  fun print() = thisSavesMeTyping.forEach { Log.d("ugh", it.toString()) }
}

class MyModel : ViewModel() {
  val source: SourceOfTruth =
      SourceOfTruth().apply {
        add(
            Task("exercise", 30).apply {
              createRecord("push ups")
              createRecord("sit ups")
            })
        add(Task("dishes", 10))
      }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      val myModel: MyModel by viewModels()
      val tasks = myModel.source.toMutableStateList()
      Column {
        tasks.forEach { task ->
          Row {
            Text(task.name)
            task.completions.forEach { Text(it.timeStamp.toString().dropLast(15)) }
            Button(
                onClick = {
                  task.createRecord("dummy")
                  myModel.source.print()
                }) { Text("now") }
          }
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
              tasks.add(Task("dummy task", 90))
              myModel.source.print()
            }) { Text("new Task") }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pushing the now button updates the source in the viewmodel, but doesn't trigger recomposition. Pushing the add task button triggers recomposition, but doesn't add a task to the source of truth.
Any suggestions on how I can fix those?
If you read all that, Thank you very much. I wish I could buy you a coffee or beer.

Comment: Btw the rough idea is like a todo list with a record on how many times a task has been completed, so maybe a little more time tracking than todolist

Comment: You didn't share the viewmodel.

Comment: I found a solution. I use ` val state = mutableStateOf(source, neverEqualPolicy())` then when I change something in source I can `state.value = state.value` and it recomposes. and to make the second dimension state was also simple instead of a forEach to create the columns I do `source.value.map { mutableStateOf(it, neverEqualPolicy()) }.forEach` and now I can change the second dimension of data and self assign it and only recompose the row